# python web scraping error in windows server

Tags: python, windows, web, screen-scraping

hello i am trying to scrape data from a website where login required
and the python script is working fine in my computer (windows 11) and it is loging in and scraping data
but when i try to run script in windows server 2012 R2 then i am getting forbidden access error (website connecting error) evan i am using same python version which installed in my computer and same modules version.
evan i copy my python whole folder and make it portable and then run it in windows server and still getting same connection error
then i tried proxy and proxy is also working fine in my main computer but getting same error in server.
kindely tell me is there windows os issue ?

so there is windows os files issue ?

Comment: Wich kind of proxy are you using? Most of time it's because IP of hosting company are knowed by antibot solution.

Comment: http and https. but i am not using it in whole server i just try to use in python code which will connect with specific website only

Comment: these are not proxies, they are protocols. seems like you are not using proxies. what modules are you using, share the code, share the error, share what you want to get

Comment: here are the modules list (mpegdash
tqdm
requests
python-dotenv
protobuf==3.20.0
webvtt-py
pysrt
m3u8
colorama
yt-dlp
bitstring
cloudscraper
unidecode
beautifulsoup4
lxml
six
pathvalidate
coloredlogs)

Comment: here is proxy (185.127.356.30) not exact i just replaced numbers with originals